# delete reserve word not calling destructor on first pass of loop

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, destructor

I have created a simple program that "draws" shapes within command prompt. I am using several class implementation, but the main issue is within the Command abstract class, more specifically the destructor in that class. I am compiling it with a DEBUG mode that I defined that prints a `'-'` every time the destructor deletes an object.

The Command class looks something like this:

```
class Command {
    public:
        Command(){
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << '+';
#endif
        }
        virtual ~Command() {
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << '-';
#endif
        }   
        virtual void execute() = 0;
        virtual void unexecute() = 0;
};
```

The loop I am calling within another class is as follows:

```
vector<Command*>  history_;

while(position_ != 0) {
    delete *history_.end();
    history_.pop_back();
    position_--;
}
```

if `position_` is greater than 1 it prints the `'-'` n - 1 times, but it doesn't call the destructor on the first delete of the loop.

Comment: `vector<T>::end()` does not return an iterator to a valid object.

Comment: Could it be you aren't seeing it because output is buffered?  What if you flush the buffer with `std::cout.flush()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an STL container `end()` does not references the *last item*, but the *place* just after the last item.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the last element of a vector is not `*history_.end()` it's `history_.back()`.

Now, if `position` really indicates a position, you should let it reach 0. If it is however, a count of the number of items, you should instead rename it to `count` or `size`.

Since a vector already includes the means to test when it's empty, you can even ditch your custom counter and not worry about whether it should reach 0 or not:

```
while(!history.empty()) {
    delete history_.back();
    history_.pop_back();
}
```

But since you're actually clearing out the whole vector, there's no need to pop one element at a time. You can iterate across the vector, delete them, and afterwards `clear()` the vector at once.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < history_.size(); ++i) {
    delete history[i];
}
history_.clear();
```

Or in C++11:

```
for(auto ptr : history_) {
    delete ptr;
}
history_.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because 0 will not be deleted because `position_ != 0` excludes 0 so you will be left with one command in the vector.
Change it to

```
while(position_ >= 0)
```

and then 0 will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems:

- `end()` refers to *one past the end* of the vector, it's not a valid element for you to `delete` (you've mistaken `end()` for `back()`). Since you're using a count variable to iterate through the loop, you could also use random access (ie. `history_end[i]`) to access elements in the `vector`.
- Your condition should be `position_ >= 0`, so that the 0th element can be `delete`d.